# PHP - Can't insert into a correct time format

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to do a schedule program and I want to insert into hours in my database with Ajax.

If I insert it by myself ( hardcoding ) everything is all right. But when I need to use my array, it looks like json is changing it, my first postion isnt the right one anymore, and if I insert 11:00, it only put 00:00:01 in my database.

here is my JQuery/Ajax

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $("#btnExporter").click(function(){
        //It create an array of vals from my input (if i do an alert, it works )
            var listeElement= $("input[type='text'].inputTableau")
                     .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

            $.ajax({                                                // préparation et appel AJAX
                url: "/ajax/Exporter.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({nomModele: $('#txtNomExporter').val(), arrayExportation: listeElement, departement : $('#listeDepartement').val()}),        //On envoie le contenu des inputs
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                success: 

                function(){                                     //  SUCCES: On avertie que la sauvegarde a fonctionne
                alert('Exportation réussi');                            
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                        // ERREUR AJAX, affiche le status et l'erreur
                            alert(' Erreur : ' + xhr.status + '\n' + thrownError);
                }
            });

        }); 
    </script>
```

And here is my PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../includes/errorFct.inc");
include_once("../includes/identFct.inc");
include_once("../includes/fctPhpAdm.php");
$ListeChamps = $_POST['arrayExportation'];

//Name of the schedule
$nomModele = $_POST['nomModele'];
//Departement id
$departementid = $_POST['departement'];
//The array that contains the hours
$ListeChamps = $_POST['arrayExportation'];

// Faire la connexion et en cas d'erreur en avertir l'utilisateur
    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db;
    $dbc = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
        or die('La base de donn�e semble down.');

    if ($db!='' and !@mysql_select_db($db))
        die('La base de donn�e est inaccessible.');   
   //This is working well   
   //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO MODEL_HORAIRE(idDepartement, Nom, HeureDebutLundi) VALUES (3,'Allo', '11:00');");

   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO MODEL_HORAIRE(idDepartement, Nom, HeureDebutLundi) VALUES ($departementid,'$nomModele', '$ListeChamps[0]');");

    $dbc->query($sql)
?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

***Edit*** : I forgot to ask what i want haha, I want to know if it is possible to keep my array like it is suppose to be, and how that i can keep my hour like they are in my inputs ( 11:00 instead of 00:01 ).

Thanks again!

Comment: What is the output of "$ListeChamps'
Put the next code behind the line '$ListeChamps = $_POST...':
echo '<pre>', var_dump($ListeChamps), '</pre>';

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: I dont know how to see what's the output because it's not in my index.php, it's from my ajax call. I also tried to return it and do an alert in my Jquery but it dosent work.

Comment: I'm aware tadman :(. But this is not my own website, I'm working for another compagny that actually works this way. I'm also against  this but that's how that they want me to work...

Comment: If you just put the ajax url in the browser, it will give  you the output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why 3 hours after, I'll give my solution for the others that will maybe need the same thing as me. JSON has some problem with array when you push it in AJAX. You only have to push the array with JSON.stringify() and explode it in PHP here is how it looks now ->

Jquery :

```
var listeElement= $("input[type='text'].inputTableau")
                     .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

                var jsonText = JSON.stringify(listeElement);

             $.ajax({                                               // préparation et appel AJAX
                url: "/ajax/Inscrire.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({action : "set_Inscription", arrayExportation : jsonText, departement : $('#listeDepartement').val(), employe : $('#listeEmployes').val(), 
                dateHoraire : $('#jour').val(), projet : $('#listeProjet').val(), note : $('#txtNote').val()}),     
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                success: 

                function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);                                        //  SUCCES: On avertie que la sauvegarde a fonctionne                           
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                        // ERREUR AJAX, affiche le status et l'erreur
                            alert(' Erreur : ' + xhr.status + '\n' + thrownError);
                }
            });
```

PHP

```
$ListeChamps = $_POST['arrayExportation'];
    $ListeChamps = str_replace('\"',"",$ListeChamps);
    $ListeChamps = str_replace('[',"",$ListeChamps);
    $ListeChamps = str_replace(']',"",$ListeChamps);

    $ValeurTerminale =  explode(',', $ListeChamps);

    for($i=0;$i<count($ValeurTerminale);$i++)
    {
        $ValeurTerminale[i] = mysql_real_escape_string($ValeurTerminale[i]);
    }
```

And now we have a PHP array!
Before, it was a single string so I was getting the first char of my string. That's why it was 00:00:01 and not 11:00:00.